# Using as a concrete type conforming to protocol AnyObject is not supported

Tags: swift, reference, hashtable, protocols, weak

I'm using Swift 2 and using WeakContainer as a way to store a set of weak objects, much like `NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()`

```
struct WeakContainer<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?
}

public protocol MyDelegate : AnyObject {

}
```

Then in my ViewController, I declare

```
public var delegates = [WeakContainer<MyDelegate>]
```

But it is error

> Using MyDelegate as a concrete type conforming to protocol AnyObject is not supported

I see that the error is that `WeakContainer` has `value` member declared as `weak`, so `T` is expected to be object. But I also declare `MyDelegate` as `AnyObject`, too. How to get around this?

Comment: Where is the error actually at?  And what's wrong with `NSHashTable`?

Comment: In your protocol declaration, if you change `AnyObject` to `class`, it should work fine.  Don't ask me to explain the difference though.

Comment: @nhgrif I tried `public protocol MyDelegate : class` before, it does not work

Comment: What is the error that that gives?

Comment: @nhgrif the same error in this question. `NSHashTable` is not generic, I don't want that

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/B0swn6w.png

Comment: @nhgrif still get that error. I'm on Xcode 7.0 and Swift 2. Wonder if that is fixed in Swift 2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90732/discussion-between-onmyway133-and-nhgrif).

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution to this yet? Suffering from the exact same problem...

Comment: This might be helpful, but they don't provide an exact solution either https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17942

Comment: Inheriting from `class` and `AnyObject` should be the same thing

Comment: It's not fixed yet. Here's the jira ticket describing the same problem: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1176

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same idea to create weak container with generics.
As result I created wrapper for `NSHashTable` and did some workaround for your compiler error.

```
class WeakSet<ObjectType>: SequenceType {

    var count: Int {
        return weakStorage.count
    }

    private let weakStorage = NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()

    func addObject(object: ObjectType) {
        guard object is AnyObject else { fatalError("Object (\(object)) should be subclass of AnyObject") }
        weakStorage.addObject(object as? AnyObject)
    }

    func removeObject(object: ObjectType) {
        guard object is AnyObject else { fatalError("Object (\(object)) should be subclass of AnyObject") }
        weakStorage.removeObject(object as? AnyObject)
    }

    func removeAllObjects() {
        weakStorage.removeAllObjects()
    }

    func containsObject(object: ObjectType) -> Bool {
        guard object is AnyObject else { fatalError("Object (\(object)) should be subclass of AnyObject") }
        return weakStorage.containsObject(object as? AnyObject)
    }

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<ObjectType> {
        let enumerator = weakStorage.objectEnumerator()
        return anyGenerator {
            return enumerator.nextObject() as! ObjectType?
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
protocol MyDelegate : AnyObject {
    func doWork()
}

class MyClass: AnyObject, MyDelegate {
    fun doWork() {
        // Do delegated work.
    }
}

var delegates = WeakSet<MyDelegate>()
delegates.addObject(MyClass())

for delegate in delegates {
    delegate.doWork()
}
```

It's not the best solution, because `WeakSet` can be initialized with any type, and if this type doesn't conform to `AnyObject` protocol then app will crash. But I don't see any better solution right now.

Comment: `object is AnyObject` is always true.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same problem when I tried to implement weak containers. As @plivesey points out in a comment above, this seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1176) in Swift 2.2 / Xcode 7.3, but it is [expected to work](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001637.html).

However, the problem does not occur for some Foundation protocols. For example, this compiles:

```
let container = WeakContainer<NSCacheDelegate>()
```

I found out that this works for protocols marked with the `@objc` attribute. You can use this as a workaround:

**Workaround 1**

```
@objc
public protocol MyDelegate : AnyObject { }

let container = WeakContainer<MyDelegate>() // No compiler error
```

As this can lead to other problems (some types cannot be represented in Objective-C), here is an alternative approach:

**Workaround 2**

Drop the `AnyObject` requirement from the container, and cast the value to `AnyObject` internally.

```
struct WeakContainer<T> {
  private weak var _value:AnyObject?
  var value: T? {
    get {
      return _value as? T
    }
    set {
      _value = newValue as? AnyObject
    }
  }
}

protocol MyDelegate : AnyObject { }

var container = WeakContainer<MyDelegate>() // No compiler error
```

Caveat: Setting a value that conforms to `T`, but is not an `AnyObject`, fails.

Comment: Workaround 2 works nicely here, though of course it should not be needed! Great work.

Comment: Workaround 2 saved me from a massive rewrite. Thanks @Theo

Comment: Cool guy! How did you discover Workaround2? It works really fine. And also Workaround1 just like a magic!

Comment: Get warning `Conditional cast from 'T?' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds` on line `_value = newValue as? AnyObject`. What should we do about that?

Answer (score 5):

Why are you trying to use generics? I would suggest doing the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol MyDelegate : AnyObject {

}

class WeakContainer : AnyObject {
    weak var value: MyDelegate?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegates = [WeakContainer]()
}
```

There is also `NSValue`'s `nonretainedObject`

Comment: Your suggested `WeakContainer` can only store values of type `MyDelegate`. The question is how to implement this container so that it can be reused for other protocols as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your Protocol can be marked as @obj then you can use code below

```
protocol Observerable {

    associatedtype P : AnyObject

    var delegates: NSHashTable<P> { get }
}

@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    func someFunc()

}

class SomeClass : Observerable {

    var delegates = NSHashTable<MyProtocol>.weakObjects()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `WeakContainer` requires its generic type `T` to be a subtype of `AnyObject` - a `protocol` declaration *is not* a subtype of `AnyObject`.  You have four options:

1. Instead of declaring `WeakContainer<MyDelegate>` replace it with something that actually implements `MyDelegate`.  The Swift-y approach for this is to use the `AnyX` pattern: `struct AnyMyDelegate : MyDelegate { ... }`
2. Define `MyDelegate` to be 'class bound' as `protocol MyDelegate : class { ... }`
3. Annotate `MyDelegate` with `@obj` which, essentially, makes it 'class bound'
4. Reformulate `WeakContainer` to *not* require its generic type to inherit from `AnyObject`.  You'll be hard pressed to make this work because you need a property declared as `weak var` and there are limitation as to what types are accepted by `weak var` - which are `AnyObject` essentially.

Comment: As to option 2: Doesn't `class` have the same effect as `AnyObject` here? It didn't seem to make a difference when I tried it. As to option 4: As far as I understand, inheritance from `AnyObject` is the only way to make the generic type class-bound. Could you provide example implementations for options 2 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of WeakSet in pure Swift (without NSHashTable).

```
internal struct WeakBox<T: AnyObject> {
    internal private(set) weak var value: T?
    private var pointer: UnsafePointer<Void>
    internal init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.pointer = unsafeAddressOf(value)
    }
}


extension WeakBox: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.pointer.hashValue
    }
}


extension WeakBox: Equatable {}

func ==<T>(lhs: WeakBox<T>, rhs: WeakBox<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.pointer == rhs.pointer
}



public struct WeakSet<Element>: SequenceType {
    private var boxes = Set<WeakBox<AnyObject>>()

    public mutating func insert(member: Element) {
        guard let object = member as? AnyObject else {
            fatalError("WeakSet's member (\(member)) must conform to AnyObject protocol.")
        }

        self.boxes.insert(WeakBox(object))
    }

    public mutating func remove(member: Element) {
        guard let object = member as? AnyObject else {
            fatalError("WeakSet's member (\(member)) must conform to AnyObject protocol.")
        }

        self.boxes.remove(WeakBox(object))
    }

    public mutating func removeAll() {
        self.boxes.removeAll()
    }

    public func contains(member: Element) -> Bool {
        guard let object = member as? AnyObject else {
            fatalError("WeakSet's member (\(member)) must conform to AnyObject protocol.")
        }

        return self.boxes.contains(WeakBox(object))
    }

    public func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Element> {
        var generator = self.boxes.generate()

        return AnyGenerator {
            while(true) {
                guard let box = generator.next() else {
                    return nil
                }

                guard let element = box.value else {
                    continue
                }

                return element as? Element
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not compile with swift 3