# Generic constraint for any protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Is it possible to constrain generic type to accept protocol in Swift?

I have implemented wrapper to have weak list of objects, and I need to extend that to protocols.

```
protocol Incrementable: class {
    func inc()
}

class Counter: Incrementable {
    var n: Int = 0

    func inc() {
        n += 1
    }
}

struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value : T?
    init (value: T?)
    {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var cnt: Counter? = Counter()

let counters : [Weak<Counter>] = [Weak(value: cnt), Weak(value: Counter())]

for counter in counters
{
    counter.value?.inc()
}
```

Now if I want to store any object that implements `Incrementable` I have to use `AnyObject` and that is not very type safe and also includes `as?` casting

```
let counters : [Weak<AnyObject>] = [Weak(value: cnt), Weak(value: Counter())]

for counter in counters
{
    (counter.value as? Incrementable)?.inc()
}
```

And code I would like to have would be

```
let counters: [Weak<Incrementable>] = [Weak(value: cnt), Weak(value: Counter())]

for counter in counters
{
    counter.value?.inc()
}
```

Of course, above code cannot be compiled and fails with:

> Using 'Incrementable' as concrete type conforming to protocol
>   'AnyObject' is not supported

Is it possible to write `Weak` wrapper so it can accept and store weak references to protocol?

---

While root cause of my problem is same as in [Using as a concrete type conforming to protocol AnyObject is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807948/using-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-anyobject-is-not-supported) that question deals with hash tables and I need solution with lists that allows duplicate entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using as a concrete type conforming to protocol AnyObject is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807948/using-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-anyobject-is-not-supported)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I don't think that is duplicate, but with help of that Q&A I managed to get better solution for my problem, and I posted it as answer. However, if anyone has better suggestions/solutions I am all ears.

Comment: Why is `AnyObject` not enough?  The only other option are structs and I am not really sure how weak references should be working with structs?

Comment: @Sulthan It should be enough, but with `AnyObject` constraint it will not accept protocols. That is Swift limitation. Some other languages are capable of using generic constraints that allow both object and protocol (interface) references.

Comment: @Sulthan `weak` does not work with structs.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I see, you needed class protocols. Sorry for my slow understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705465/4267244) pointed me in right direction and I was able to come up with following solution for implementing weak list of protocol references that allows duplicates and `nil` (convenience) entries.

```
struct Weak<T>
{
    weak var value: AnyObject?
    init (value: T?)
    {
        if value != nil
        {
            guard value is AnyObject else { fatalError("Object (\(value)) should be subclass of AnyObject") }
            self.value = value as? AnyObject
        }
    }
}

class WeakList<T>: SequenceType
{
    var items : [Weak<T>] = []

    func add(item: T?)
    {
        items.append(Weak(value: item))
    }

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<T>
    {
        var nextIndex = items.count - 1

        return anyGenerator
        {
            while nextIndex >= 0
            {
                let item = self.items[nextIndex--]
                if item.value != nil
                {
                   return item.value as? T
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let incrementables = WeakList<Incrementable>()

incrementables.add(Counter())
incrementables.add(cnt)
incrementables.add(nil)
incrementables.add(Counter())
incrementables.add(cnt)

for counter in incrementables
{
    counter.inc()
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! After finding dead ends for this issue. Even stopping at the heart of the issue: Conforming to <T> (without constraints) and underneath holding a `weak` `AnyObject`. All the rest can be freely sugarcoated with getter/setter subscripts as pleased. This answer is really underrated.

Comment: not sure of Swift's implementation 6 years ago, but today, `is AnyObject` always returns true. so the check in the wrapper's initializer doesn't guard against giving it non reference types — making this wrapper intended for reference types liable for unexpected behavior.

Comment: @shoe You are right. At some point AnyObject changed. This code is older.