# Using protocol as a concrete type conforming to 'AnyObject' is not supported

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics

I'm trying to implement a simple multi-delegate situation:

```
protocol Subscribable: class {
    associatedtype Subscriber: AnyObject
    var subscribers: NSHashTable<Subscriber> { get }
}

protocol ControllerSubscriber: class {
    func controllerDidSomething()
}

class Controller: Subscribable {
    typealias Subscriber = ControllerSubscriber
    var subscribers = NSHashTable<Subscriber>.weakObjects()  // Error
}
```

> Error: Using 'ControllerSubscriber' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported.

My question is:

- What does this error mean exactly?
- What are the underlying concepts the thing I'm trying to do fails for?
- Why is this "not supported"?

And of course, how do I work around this? In the sense of an actual solution not a work around.

I have such a hard time understanding Swift's generics system. I seem to be running into seemingly simple situations like this constantly. I just want to put a thing conforming to a protocol into another thing :( . I would like to know where my thinking goes wrong so I can fix it and never have to see these errors again.

There is [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807948/using-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-anyobject-is-not-supported) but please note the answers give only workarounds, no explanations or solutions.

Comment: See the Q&A [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) (which should answer your first 3 (and maybe even last) questions) and [Unable to use protocol as associatedtype in another protocol in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360114/unable-to-use-protocol-as-associatedtype-in-another-protocol-in-swift) which should answer your last question.

Comment: The whole problem is that protocols don't always conform to themselves – therefore you cannot use an abstract type (such as `ControllerSubscriber`) as a concrete type that conforms to `AnyObject`.

Comment: Late response: Thank you for the links, that was a good starting point! From everything I've read so far it seems to be "It is because it is but nobody has any idea why." Honestly, stuff likes this is really bringing my enthusiasm down for Swift. I don't see myself writing type-erased wrappers for all cases I want to use this subscriber pattern for. Anyway. In the second link, you proposed several alternative solutions. Do you see any alternatives in this case apart from type-erased wrappers? Thank you again for your response.

Comment: Depends on whether your `subscribers` property needs to be an `NSHashTable` of heterogenous element types that conform to `ControllerSubscriber`. If that is the case, then as far as I'm aware, a type erasure is your only option. If you `subscribers` property only needs to be an `NSHashTable` of homogenous elements that conform to `ControllerSubscriber`, then you could solve the problem by introducing a generic placeholder to `Controller` in order to define the concrete type of element in the hash table. Although AFAIK, those are the only two practical solutions to your problem as it stands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not fair to blame this problem on Swift. Reasoning about types seems to be some meta-art we will first have to get used to (unless you have been sitting on the C++ standards committee for the last 30 years that is :-).

Turns out your problem is related to your choice of `NSHashTable` as the data structure to hold your `subscribers`. The following would compile with minimal changes:

```
protocol Subscribable: class {
    associatedtype Subscriber
    var subscribers: [Subscriber?] { get }
}

protocol ControllerSubscriber: class {
    func controllerDidSomething()
}

class Controller: Subscribable {
    typealias Subscriber = ControllerSubscriber
    var subscribers = [Subscriber?]()
}
```

however, it lacks the `weak` semantics and is not really useful yet. The list of `subscribers` is exhibited as a property and has to be manipulated directly by the clients. Furthermore each implementation of `Subscribable` has to implement its own notification mechanism and there is hardly any logic that is centralised by this approach. Technically you can use it like this:

```
class Controller: Subscribable {
    typealias Subscriber = ControllerSubscriber
    var subscribers = [Subscriber?]()

    func notify() {
        for case let subscriber? in subscribers {
            subscriber.controllerDidSomething()
        }
    }
}

var controller = Controller()

class IWillSubscribe : ControllerSubscriber {
    func controllerDidSomething() {
        print("I got something")
    }
}

controller.subscribers.append(IWillSubscribe())
controller.notify()
```

but that is neither very practical nor very readable. This would have been an acceptable solution (since it was the only one) up to Java 7, but even in Java 8 (and much more so in Swift) we would like to encapsulate the notification logic into the `Subscribable` protocol as a default implementation, but that would be another post.

Since you chose to implement `subscribers` as an `NSHashTable` (there is probably an ARC reason to desire weak references here) there seems to be some Objective-C trickery involved. After much experimentation (and finally finding the fourth answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807948/using-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-anyobject-is-not-supported#comment53452877_32807948) I got the following to work:

```
protocol Subscribable: class {
    associatedtype Subscriber : AnyObject
    var subscribers: NSHashTable<Subscriber> { get }
}

@objc protocol ControllerSubscriber: class {
    func controllerDidSomething()
}

class Controller: Subscribable {
    typealias Subscriber = ControllerSubscriber
    var subscribers = NSHashTable<Subscriber>.weakObjects()

    func notify() {
        for subscriber in subscribers.allObjects {
            subscriber.controllerDidSomething()
        }
    }
}

var controller = Controller()

class IWillSubscribe : ControllerSubscriber {
    func controllerDidSomething() {
        print("I got something")
    }
}

let iDoSubscribe = IWillSubscribe()
controller.subscribers.add(iDoSubscribe)
controller.notify()
```

which is virtually identical to your original (with some proof around it). As it seems Objective-C `@protocol`s are not *quite* the same as Swift `protocol`s, but Swift *can* actually do either.

There is quite a lot of subtlety in this though, only `allObjects` works without type erasure, your trusty `objectEnumerator` only returns `Any?` and that is a stupid animal to get anything from. Also note that

```
let iDoSubscribe = IWillSubscribe()
```

is instrumental. At first I tried

```
controller.subscribers.add(IWillSubscribe())
```

which actually added something to the `count` of `subscribers`, but went away with any attempt to iterate (as one should expect from a `weak` reference that is not referred to anywhere else).

A very late answer that is already way too long, just to prove that this is *still* an issue, even with Swift 3. Maybe this will get better once [this Jira ticket](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1176) is resolved.