# Return Class based on Generic in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics

I have two custom class objects. I have to show a view which reads the data from both the objects depending on what class object we passed.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can set your myObject as AnyObject and after you can check object is from class A or class B.

```
class viewc : UIViewController {
    var myObject: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let object = myObject as? ClassA {
            print("Object is of class- ClassA")
        }else if let object = myObject as? ClassB {
            print("Object is of class- ClassB")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I can not define the myObject with **AnyObject** ,  it must be defined either A or B only

Comment: which version of swift are you using?

Comment: I am using swift 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like `var object = <T>()` as its not the correct format or `var object = T()` as Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization.

You can use it like this:-

```
class ABC<T>: UIViewController{

    var object: T? = nil
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: But I think T is also need to defined,isn't it? Because T is only can A or B, nothing else

Comment: No when you call this controller, you need to pass it in argument like we do in generics, like:- ABC<A> or ABC<B>

Comment: this is not useful to me , I must have to say either it type A or B , otherwise my code will work to parse data.

Comment: If its only of two type then you don't need to use generic, you can just do it by using a variable to type AnyObject.

Comment: But I already prase data using type A object. But Now I have to parse using type B object, both are close to similar

So I can not use AnyObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type.

```
class ControllerTimeline<T>: UIViewController {

    var myObject :T?
    ...
}
```

If you need T to have some constraint (example: could be only NSObject)

```
class ControllerTimeline<T: NSObject>: UIViewController {

    var myObject :T?
    ...
}
```

If you want to use only A or B, you can create a common parent for A and B+

```
class ControllerTimeline<T: C>: UIViewController {
...
```

Or let A and B implement a common protocol and type something like this

```
class ControllerTimeline<T: MyProtocol>: UIViewController {
...
```

Comment: But I think T is also need to defined,isn't it?

Comment: That's the core of using generics,  'T' is a placeholder type name that doesn’t say anything about what T must be.

Comment: But I have to say like T can be either A or B only, otherwise I can not parse.

Comment: If you need some type constraint, make A and B conform to a protocol, then add a Type constraint
class ViewController<T: MyProtocol>

Comment: can you able to give an example?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Of course. You need A and B to conform that protocol.

Comment: You have to this workaround to make the protocol solution work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807948/using-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-protocol-anyobject-is-not-supported.