# Swift dictionary with weak reference keys?

Tags: swift, dictionary, weak

Let's say I have a some objects representing network connections. Once these connections are disconnected, the associated objects disappear. I don't want to hang on to a connection object which is no longer connected.

I also want to associate some data with these connections using a dictionary. So I might have the code:

```
class Connection { ... }
class Metadata { ... }

var metadata: [Connection: Metadata] = [:]
```

But the above code means that the dictionary will keep references to the `Connection` objects which I don't want. I'd prefer to have the associated entries be removed, ideally automatically, when the `Connection` objects disappear.

So I tried:

```
var metadata: [weak Connection: Metadata] = [:]
```

But this doesn't work. What is a good alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are describing an NSMapTable. It gives you a dictionary-like thing with weak references to its keys and/or values.

Comment: Just a note to everyone writing Swift on the server: `NSMapTable` and `NSHashTable` does not exist on Linux, so you'll need to use an approach like Rob's answer.

Comment: Except that NSMapTable's weak keys are broken: key objects do not get actually released and are being held by internal implementation details.

Comment: @Kentzo I think "broken" is rather inappropriate. There are some good articles about how it works.

Comment: I'm referring an issue as described [here](http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/). To my best knowledge it's still as broken as it was 8 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a generic type for weak references like they did in [How do I declare an array of weak references in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24127587/1271826) Because you are doing this for the dictionary key, you have to go through some extra work to make it conform to `Hashable`, but it can be done.

Personally, though, I wouldn't use the connection objects as the key. I use a unique string identifier for the network request be the key (e.g., the [`taskIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionTask/taskIdentifier) of the `NSURLSessionTask`).

That resolves the concern of the collection maintaining a strong reference to the request.

Regarding the removing of the item when the task is done, I just make this clean-up part of the task completion logic.