# Cannot assign weak to custom array

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references

I am getting this error `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '[ExerciseSet]'` when trying to make a custom array object to weak. Why can't I assign weak to this type?

```
class Session {
    weak var sets: [ExerciseSet]?    
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127587/how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-weak-references-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because Swift Arrays are structs, not classes. If you want to have a weak reference to an array in Swift, you will need to use a wrapper object like so:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
   let value: T
}
```

then change your class to the following:

```
class Session {
   weak var sets: Wrapper<[ExerciseSet]?>
}
```

That being said, it probably doesn't make sense to use a weak reference here. Your session is probably either a singleton or an object that stays in memory your entire application lifecycle.

Unless you actually need to know whether the property was set or not, you can also probably use `[ExerciseSet]` instead of making it optional, then use an empty array when you don't have any values.

Comment: when the user completes a session that data is saved to CoreData, and then all the session are organized in a tableView, in that case would it be better to make the sets a weak var?