# Why weakifying a strong reference by using a local variable doesn't work?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, unowned-references

(I understand how ARC works and the difference between `weak` and `unowned`. The question is about a specific use of them and why it doesn't work. I'll use `unowned` in the example below just for simplicity.)

See example below. Note line 10, which is intended to change the passed strong reference to an unowned reference. I thought this would work, but when I used it in my code recently I found I was wrong.

```
 1  import Foundation
   
 2  class MyClass {
 3      var uuid: UUID = UUID()
 4      
 5      deinit {
 6          print("Deinited!")
 7      }
 8  }
   
 9  func test(_ d: inout [UUID:MyClass], _ o: MyClass) {
10      unowned let u = o  // <- !
11      d[u.uuid] = u
12  }
   
13  var d = [UUID: MyClass]()
14  test(&d, MyClass())
```

Run the above code in Playground. The result shows that deinit isn't called, indicating a strong reference to the object is saved in the dictionary.

I wonder why? Does `weak` and `unowned` keyword only applies to property? But the above code doesn't generate compiler error and the Swift [book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) does mention it can be used in variable declaration:

> You indicate an unowned reference by placing the unowned keyword
> before a property or variable declaration.

Can anyone share how you understand it? Thanks!

BTW, I know how to solve the issue (for example, using a wrapper like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128121/10120633)). What I try to understand is why the above code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect otherwise. Dictionaries are designed to hold strong references to things. That's just how they work. That extra unowned reference to what `o` refers to, called `u`, is completely irrelevant to how the dictionary stores its references.

Comment: @Sweeper This is where I'm confused. So, do you mean that it depends on the type that stores the reference to decide whether strong or weak reference is stored? I thought it depends on the type of the reference the caller passes to the type (dictionary in this case). I believe I'm missing something. Would you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Let me put it this way. If I passes a weak reference to a dictionary, how can it store strong reference? The real underlying question is: how exactly is strong/weak reference implemented? (I have searched for information about this but haven't found any yet).

Comment: "Exactly how strong/weak references are implemented" isn't particularly related to this question, I feel. It seems like you just have a misunderstanding of what `=` means, which I have clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning (`a = b`), **you can't control what kind of reference `a` is. You can only control what object `a` refer to.**

Here:

```
d[u.uuid] = u
```

The code is *not* saying:

> The value associated with the key `u.uuid` in `d` is set to the (unowned) reference `u`.

It's saying:

> The value associated with the key `u.uuid` in `d` is a reference (not saying what kind) that *refers to what `u` is referring to*.

The fact that `u` is unowned is rather irrelevant. Dictionaries will always store strong references to objects. That's just how they are designed.

In the case of the [`Weak<T>` wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24128121/10120633), the dictionary will still store a strong reference to `Weak<T>`, but `Weak<T>` will store a weak reference to the wrapped `T` object. That's how it achieves not having a strong reference to the `T` object.

Comment: I realized what you comment meant by myself before I saw the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Sweeper's answer contains all the points I'll give below. But I'll try to make them a bit more explicit:

- Variable represents a storage (a location in memory)
- Assignment operation changes the value in the storage
- `weak` and `unowned` are attributes of the storage. They are **not** affected by assignment operation.

So the `unowned` keyword in line 10 in my example code affects only that specific storage location (it's in stack) and have no influence on the attribute of storage used by the global dictionary (as @Sweeper pointed out).